# Download JRE 8 but version still says 1.7.0_95

Tags: java, javafx, download

I need JRE 8 so I can utilize- javaFX, but when I check my "java -version" on MobaXterm it still says 1.7.0_95. Is there another step I need to do besides downloading it from Oracle?

Comment: I'm not sure about MobaXterm but for Eclipse, after you install it, you simply choose which JRE version to use in the build path.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to update the PATH environment variable.  That will determines what binary gets executed when you run `java` from a command prompt / shell.

It might even be that you >>just<< need to restart your command shell.

Reference:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: That is what I figured at first but it seems to already be updated. I see this C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\

Comment: Where do you see that?

Comment: In Environment Variables in the Path variable

Comment: What does "echo %PATH%" say in the command prompt what you are running "java --version"?  Show me the complete value.

Comment: C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\FusionEngine;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin

Comment: I bet that `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath` or one of the other pre-existing directories on the path contains the offending version of `java`.

Comment: Would searching through each path then deleting the path with the old version potentially solve the problem?